# Others can't read my annotated PDFs

Tags: ios, ipad, mail.app, software-recommendation, pdf

I annotate PDFs in the Mail app on iOS with the pen. Some people complain that they cannot see the annotations at all. On my Mac, using Preview, I can see everything well.

Things I tried:

- Printing as a PDF and sending this PDF; doesn't help.
- Converting the PDFs to a sequence of images using ImageMagick, I see a big black overlay box that extends to the outermost annotations in the PDF, rendering the text underneath illegible (see screenshot). Same happens using Firefox/pdf.js
- Export PDF using Skim: Works (at least if I open the new PDF in Firefox), but annotations become b/w

Is there any workaround better than physically printing out and scanning? At best, impacting my workflow the least possible?

[image]